# How to make lstm/rnn focus more on certain parts of time series while less on other parts using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

I have a time series prediction problem where most of the observed values (95%) are 0s while remaining values are non-zeros. How can I make use of RNN for this problem.

I want to predict surface flow from environmental data(air temperature, rainfall, humidity etc). We know surface flow is 0.0 for most of the time in an year. However, I also don't want to simply ignore 0s as the 0s represent the period of the year when when surface flow is 0.0. The image below shows possible observed output and three inputs. The three inputs here are just random but in reality they will be data like rainfall, humidity etc and these input data have some periodic pattern.

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import psutil
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
print(sys.version)
print('tensorflow version: ', tf.__version__)


#clean computation graph
tf.reset_default_graph()

tf.set_random_seed(777)  # reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)

def MinMaxScaler(data):    
    numerator = data - np.min(data, 0)
    denominator = np.max(data, 0) - np.min(data, 0)
    # noise term prevents the zero division
    return numerator / (denominator + 1e-7)

class generate_data(object):

    def __init__(self, data_len,  in_series, y_pred, seq_lengths, method='sum' ):
        self.data_len = data_len
        self.data = None
        self.in_series = in_series #number of input series
        self.y_pred = y_pred  #number of final outputs from model
        self.seq_lengths = seq_lengths
        self.method = method

    def _f(self, x):
        y = 0
        result = []
        for _ in x:
            result.append(y)
            y += np.random.normal(scale=1)
        return np.array(result)

    def _runningMean(self, x, N):
        return np.convolve(x, np.ones((N,))/N)[(N-1):]


    def sine(self):
        DATA = np.zeros((self.data_len, self.in_series))
        xx = [None]
        data_0 = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 20, self.data_len*self.in_series))
        xx = data_0.reshape(self.data_len, self.in_series)
        DATA[:,0: self.in_series] = xx            
        y = self._get_y(DATA)
        return xx,y, DATA


    def _get_y(self, xx):
        if self.method=='sum':
            yy = np.array([np.sum(xx[i,:]) for i in range(np.shape(xx)[0])])
        elif self.method == 'mean':
              yy = np.array([np.mean(xx[i,:]) for i in range(np.shape(xx)[0])])

        elif self.method == 'self_mul':
            yy = np.array([np.prod(xx[i,:]) for i in range(np.shape(xx)[0])])
        elif self.method == 'mean_mirror':
            yy = np.array([np.mean(xx[i,:]) for i in range(np.shape(xx)[0])])
        return yy


    def normalize(self, xx1,yy1):

        yy = [None]*len(yy1)
        YMinMax = {}

        xx = MinMaxScaler(xx1)
        for i in range(self.y_pred):
            YMinMax['ymin_' + str(i)] = np.min(yy1[0])
            YMinMax['ymax_' + str(i)] = np.max(yy1[0])
            yy[i] = MinMaxScaler(yy1[0])
        setattr(self, 'YMinMax', YMinMax)
        return xx,yy


    def create_dataset(self, xx, yy, percent_of_zeros):
        '''creates a dataset consisting of windows for x and y data'''
        dataX = self._build_input_windows(xx, self.seq_lengths)

        if self.y_pred > 1:
            pass
        elif self.y_pred > 1 and self.seq_lengths != any(self.seq_lengths):
            pass
        else: 
            dataY = self._build_y_windows(yy[0] , self.seq_lengths)   

        indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(dataY.size), replace=False,
                           size=int(dataY.size * percent_of_zeros))
        dataY[indices] = 0

        return dataX, dataY


    def _build_input_windows(self, time_series, seq_length):
        dataX = []
        for i in range(0, len(time_series) - seq_length):
            _x = time_series[i:i + seq_length, :]
            dataX.append(_x)
        return np.array(dataX)   


    def _build_y_windows(self, iny, seq_length):        
        dataY = []
        for i in range(0, len(iny) - seq_length):
            _y = iny[i + seq_length, ]  # Next close price           
            dataY.append(_y)
        return  np.array(dataY)


    def TrainTestSplit(self, dataX, dataY, train_frac):

        train_size = int(len(dataY) * train_frac)            
        trainX, testX = np.array(dataX[0:train_size]), np.array(dataX[train_size:len(dataX)])

        trainY, testY = np.array(dataY[0:train_size]), np.array(dataY[train_size:len(dataY)])
        trainY = trainY.reshape(len(trainY), 1)
        testY = testY.reshape(len(testY), 1)  
        return trainX, trainY, testX, testY, train_size

#training/hyper parameters
tot_epochs = 500 
batch_size = 16
learning_rate = 0.01
seq_lengths = 5  #sequence lengths/window size for  RNN
rnn_inputs = 3 # no of inputs for  RNN
y_pred = 1
data_length = 1005  #this can be overwritten or useless
gen_data = generate_data(data_length,  rnn_inputs, y_pred, seq_lengths, 'sum')
xx,yy,data_1 = gen_data.sine() 
# xx = abs(xx)
train_frac = 0.8
xx1,yy1 = gen_data.normalize(xx,[yy])
zeros = 0.96
dataX, dataY = gen_data.create_dataset(xx1,yy1, zeros)
trainX, trainY, testX, testY, train_size = gen_data.TrainTestSplit( dataX, dataY, train_frac)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x_placeholders = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5, 3])
Y =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

plt.plot(dataY, '.', label='output')
plt.plot(xx[:,0], '.', label='input1')
plt.plot(xx[:,1], '.', label='input2')
plt.plot(xx[:,2], '.', label='input3')
plt.legend()

# build neural network
with tf.variable_scope('scope0'):  #defining  RNN
    # cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units= 7, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.tanh)
    cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(units = 128)
    outputs1, _states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_placeholders, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Y_pred1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs1[:, -1], 1, activation_fn=None)
    Y_pred1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(outputs1[:,-1])
Y_pred = Y_pred1

## cost/loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y_pred - Y))  # sum of the squares
## optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
#
## RMSE
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
predictions = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
rmse = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(targets - predictions)))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=41)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./laos_2out/cnntest', sess.graph)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    # Training step
    for epoch in range(tot_epochs):

      total_batches = int(train_size / batch_size)  ##total batches/ no. of steps in an epoch

      #for batch in range(total_batches):
      _, step_loss = sess.run([train, loss], feed_dict= {x_placeholders:trainX, Y:trainY, keep_prob:0.5} )
      print('epoch: # {} loss: {}'.format(epoch, step_loss))

#    # evaluating on test data
    test_predict = sess.run(Y_pred, feed_dict= {x_placeholders:testX, Y:trainY, keep_prob:0.5} )

    #evaluating on training data
    train_predict = sess.run(Y_pred, feed_dict={x_placeholders:trainX, Y:trainY, keep_prob:0.5})

    rmse_val = sess.run(rmse, feed_dict={targets: testY, predictions: test_predict})
    print("RMSE: {}".format(rmse_val))

# Plot predictions
  fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True)
  fig.set_figwidth(14)
  fig.set_figheight(5)
  ax2.plot(testY, 'b', label='observed')
  ax2.plot(test_predict, 'k', label='predicted')
  ax2.legend(loc="best")
  ax2.set_xlabel("Time Period")
  ax2.set_title('Testing')
  ax1.plot(trainY, 'b', label='observed')
  ax1.plot(train_predict, 'k',label= 'predicted')
  ax1.legend(loc="best")
  ax1.set_xlabel("Time Period")
  ax1.set_ylabel("discharge (cms)")
  ax1.set_title('Training')
  plt.show()
```

The problem is that while training, the model focuses on majority of values i.e. 0s and thus makes the predictions equal to 0s. How can I make the model focus on non-zero values (positive surface flow) while at the same time also consider 0s (when there is no surface flow). I have read about attention mechanism but have not understood that how I can implement it in such scenarios.